# Does .withUnsafePointerToElements() protect against premature deallocation of a Swift array?

Tags: swift

When writing a wrapper function to perform an FFT operation in Swift, I arrived at two different ways of passing a Swift array into Accelerate functions that take C array pointers. The first uses `.withUnsafePointerToElements()`:

```
func fft(var inputArray:[Double]) -> [Double] {
    var fftMagnitudes = [Double](count:inputArray.count, repeatedValue:0.0)
    inputArray.withUnsafePointerToElements {(inputArrayPointer: UnsafePointer<Double>) -> () in
        var zeroArray = [Double](count:inputArray.count, repeatedValue:0.0)
        zeroArray.withUnsafePointerToElements { (zeroArrayPointer: UnsafePointer<Double>) -> () in
            var splitComplexInput = DSPDoubleSplitComplex(realp: inputArrayPointer, imagp: zeroArrayPointer)

            vDSP_fft_zipD(fft_weights, &splitComplexInput, 1, vDSP_Length(log2(CDouble(inputArray.count))), FFTDirection(FFT_FORWARD));
            vDSP_zvmagsD(&splitComplexInput, 1, &fftMagnitudes, 1, vDSP_Length(inputArray.count));
        }
    }

    return sqrt(fftMagnitudes)
}
```

and the second merely passes the Swift arrays in using &:

```
func fft(var inputArray:[Double]) -> [Double] {
    var fftMagnitudes = [Double](count:inputArray.count, repeatedValue:0.0)
    var zeroArray = [Double](count:inputArray.count, repeatedValue:0.0)
    var splitComplexInput = DSPDoubleSplitComplex(realp: &inputArray, imagp: &zeroArray)

    vDSP_fft_zipD(fft_weights, &splitComplexInput, 1, vDSP_Length(log2(CDouble(inputArray.count))), FFTDirection(FFT_FORWARD));
    vDSP_zvmagsD(&splitComplexInput, 1, &fftMagnitudes, 1, vDSP_Length(inputArray.count));

    return sqrt(fftMagnitudes)
}
```

Both appear to operate in the same manner, with the latter being cleaner and shorter. However, I'm not sure if the second way of doing this opens me up to the local `inputArray` copy and the `zeroArray` array being deallocated via ARC after their last usage (like [what happens here](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/arc-gotcha-unexpectedly-short-lifetimes/)), leaving a dangling pointer to an array that no longer exists.

It seems that `.withUnsafePointerToElements()` has to serve some purpose, but I can't quite figure out what it is. Is it required to guarantee the lifetime of the backing arrays in the above, or am I safe simply using & to pass these arrays into C functions?

Comment: I think that withUnsafePointerToElements exists only because it was not possible to pass &array in previous betas.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you do need to extend the lifetimes. I originally wrote my FFT code like your second example, but I've grown to believe this is unsafe. The problem is that the docs only seem to promise that a `&` reference will protect you from destruction until the end of the function call. So `zeroArray` in this case would be protected until the end of the `DSPDoubleSplitComplex` line. Since `DSPDoubleSplitComplex` just holds `UnsafePointer`, I don't see any reason to believe that can extend the life of `zeroArray`. (I assume the same applies to `inputArray`.)

I'm doing it a little differently that I think reads a little better:

```
  // Generate a split complex vector from the real data
  var realp = [Double](count:Int(fftLength), repeatedValue:0.0)
  var imagp = realp

  withExtendedLifetime(realp) { () -> () in
    withExtendedLifetime(imagp) { 
      var splitComplex = DSPDoubleSplitComplex(realp:&realp, imagp:&imagp)
      ctozD(ConstUnsafePointer(signal), 2, &splitComplex, 1, fftLength)

      // Take the fft
      fft_zripD(fftsetup, &splitComplex, 1, log2N, FFTDirection(kFFTDirection_Forward))

      ... rest of fft
    }
  }
```

I'm avoiding the extra pointer variable by using `withExtendedLiftetime`. I then can just use `&realp` and `&imagp` directly. The one required `() -> () in` can be eliminated this way if you like:

```
func withExtendedLifetime<T>(x: T, f: () -> () ) {
  return Swift.withExtendedLifetime(x, f)
}

...
  withExtendedLifetime(realp) {
    withExtendedLifetime(imagp) {
      var splitComplex = DSPDoubleSplitComplex(realp:&realp, imagp:&imagp)
      ctozD(ConstUnsafePointer(signal), 2, &splitComplex, 1, fftLength)
...
```

*Totally off-topic, but I notice you pass the real component in directly without calling `ctozD`. I thought [Data Packing for Real FFTs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/UsingFourierTransforms/UsingFourierTransforms.html) indicates that you need to reorganize before calling `fft_*`. Your math is generally better than mine, so I may be missing something here. My full version is https://gist.github.com/rnapier/399676bd389c270e7b66*

Comment: Now that you mention it, I do need to check on that data packing. I might have copied that wrong from my older code. I wonder, would it be possible to construct a version of your `withExtendedLifetime()` function that took a variable number of inputs, nesting guarantees for all of them within a single function call? Could clean things up further when dealing with multiple variables, if it was possible.

Comment: I've been trying, but I don't love the results so far. https://gist.github.com/rnapier/0d24ca74e4b4c5bfb3b4

Comment: OK, might have something workable up there. I don't really love it, though.

Comment: But the technique of just writing generic versions for one parameter, two parameters, three parameters, etc. does seem to have a long pedigree in generic programming :D Scala has several generics that have 22 versions (and you see similar things in Swift with withUnsafePointers). Look at the bottom of my first example for a withExtendedLifetimes that takes 2. https://gist.github.com/rnapier/399676bd389c270e7b66 (not saying I *like* that fact, just noting that it seems to be a common technique)

Comment: Will a variadic function always have the list absorb the last parameter, even if it's explicitly called out? Is that a rational thing to ask for in a feature request? The one, two, three parameter variants will probably handle most things, in any case, and are probably good enough.

Comment: The problem is that the variadic must be the last parameter (and removing that requirement is very difficult in a world with overloads). You can side-step with currying: `f(x: Int...)(y: Int)`. The problem is if `x` is `Any` and `y` is a function, then you can't drop the extra parens. It has to be `f(1,2)({...})` (and you get surprising, but correct, errors on f(1,2){...}`). But `print()` just gave me another, horrible idea. Maybe I can decompose a tuple... Wow does that sound crazy. Let's try it.